# XML string parsing nested tag with same attribute name

Tags: java, xml, list

I am  parsing xml string from sql server. But my xml string is having nested tag, I am sharing xml string.

```
<abc sn="ahdahsdaud" family="abc" style="Aa" model="abc111222">
<part number="7N8901160101" fnum="5" qty="1.000" uom="EA">
<l2part number="075-76067-000" fnum="9000" qty="0.000" uom="EA" />
</part>
<part number="392-41230-001" fnum="440" qty="1.000" uom="EA">
<l2part number="092-41230-000" fnum="9000" qty="0.000" uom="EA" />
</part>
</abc>
```

so here I am getting part tag attributes by using the following code:

```
List<abBOM> list = new ArrayList<abBOM>();//pojo
  abBOM abbom = null;

  while(rs.next()){
      SQLXML plan = rs.getSQLXML("XMLATT");//XMLAttribute
      String xmlstr=plan.getString();
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlstr)));
      document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
     // System.out.println(root.getNodeName());
      NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("part");
     // System.out.println("size"+nList.getLength());
      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
      {
         Node node = nList.item(temp);
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
         {
            Element eElement = (Element) node;

            //System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("number").item(0).getTextContent());

            abbom = new abBOM();
            abbom.setNumber(eElement.getAttribute("number"));
            abbom.setfindNumber(eElement.getAttribute("fnum"));
            abbom.setQty(eElement.getAttribute("qty"));
            abbom.setUom(eElement.getAttribute("uom"));

            list.add(abbom);
         }
      }
  }
```

Output List:

```
[[7N8901160101,5,1.000,EA], [392-41230-001,440,1.000,EA]]
```

I want to store l2part tag attributes in the same list ie. part attributes then l2part attributes like that. Plz suggest any way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the code. What are you struggling with?

Comment: In output list this all are the part tag related attributes. I want l2part attributes also.

Comment: Then you have to look for the `l2part` parse it like you already did.

Comment: I want the attribute values like part then l2part attributes then again next part and so on..

Comment: One more requirement I want to add 1 for part and 2 for l2part that is I want output should be printed like this [[1,7N8901160101,5,1.000,EA], [2,075-76067-000,,0.000,EA], [1,392-41230-001,440,1.000,EA], [2,092-41230-000,,0.000,EA]] ..plz suggest any idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat the loop, inside, something like this:

```
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("part");
// System.out.println("size"+nList.getLength());
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
{
   Element eElement = (Element) nList.item(temp);    

   // System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("number").item(0).getTextContent());

   abbom = new abBOM();
   abbom.setNumber(eElement.getAttribute("number"));
   abbom.setfindNumber(eElement.getAttribute("fnum"));
   abbom.setQty(eElement.getAttribute("qty"));
   abbom.setUom(eElement.getAttribute("uom"));

   list.add(abbom);

   NodeList list2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("l2part");
   for (int t2 = 0; t2 < list2.getLength(); t2++)
   {
      eElement = (Element) list2.item(t2);
      abBOM abbom2 = new abBOM();
      abbom2.setNumber(eElement.getAttribute("number"));
      abbom2.setfindNumber(eElement.getAttribute("fnum"));
      abbom2.setQty(eElement.getAttribute("qty"));
      abbom2.setUom(eElement.getAttribute("uom"));
      list.add(abbom2);
   }
}
```

Comment: One more requirement I want to add 1 for part and 2 for l2part that is I want output should be printed like this [[1,7N8901160101,5,1.000,EA], [2,075-76067-000,,0.000,EA], [1,392-41230-001,440,1.000,EA], [2,092-41230-000,,0.000,EA]] ..plz suggest any idea...

Comment: One more requirement I want to add 1 for part and 2 for l2part that is I want output should be printed like this [[1,7N8901160101,5,1.000,EA], [2,075-76067-000,,0.000,EA], [1,392-41230-001,440,1.000,EA], [2,092-41230-000,,0.000,EA]] ..plz suggest any idea...

Comment: abbom.setLevel(1);
             abbom.setNumber(eElement.getAttribute("number"));
             abbom.setfindNumber(eElement.getAttribute("findNumber"));
             abbom.setQty(eElement.getAttribute("qty"));
             abbom.setUom(eElement.getAttribute("uom"));

Comment: I have added like this in abbom class as integer value but it is not working

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Throws an exception? What Exception?

Comment: I got the solution.. :)

Comment: Would you share with us?

Comment: In abBOM class file I made changes like:

Comment: @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return "["+level+","+number + ","+findNumber + ","+qty + ","+uom +"]";
    }

Answer (score 0):

Read the l2part as a new NodeList once you're processing the part element.

You can refactor your code to do it recursively. Assume that you XML is as simple as you show:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class T {
    static String data = "<abc sn=\"ahdahsdaud\" family=\"abc\" style=\"Aa\" model=\"abc111222\">\n" +
            "<part number=\"7N8901160101\" fnum=\"5\" qty=\"1.000\" uom=\"EA\">\n" +
            "<l2part number=\"075-76067-000\" fnum=\"9000\" qty=\"0.000\" uom=\"EA\" />\n" +
            "</part>\n" +
            "<part number=\"392-41230-001\" fnum=\"440\" qty=\"1.000\" uom=\"EA\">\n" +
            "<l2part number=\"092-41230-000\" fnum=\"9000\" qty=\"0.000\" uom=\"EA\" />\n" +
            "</part>\n" +
            "</abc>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(data)));
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        // System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("part");
        // System.out.println("size"+nList.getLength());
        processNodeList(nList);
    }

    private static void processNodeList(NodeList nList) {
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node node = nList.item(temp);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                //System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("number").item(0).getTextContent());
                abbom = new abBOM();
                abbom.setNumber(eElement.getAttribute("number"));
                abbom.setfindNumber(eElement.getAttribute("fnum"));
                abbom.setQty(eElement.getAttribute("qty"));
                abbom.setUom(eElement.getAttribute("uom"));

                list.add(abbom);

                NodeList lpart2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("l2part");
                processNodeList(lpart2);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that if you have nested levels of l2part they will be processed too. Otherwise it will read an empty list. Might need refinement depending on your data